# Unwanted kerning inside em-dash when using microtype

Tags: pdftex, microtype, kerning

I'm using microtype together with XCharter font. I have to add some space around en-dash and this works perfectly. Now I introduced some em-dashes with `'---'` but these are rendered by pdflatex as **an en-dash followed by a dash**.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[kerning]{microtype}

\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{XCharter-TLF}{bch} %% made XCharter equal to Bitstream Charter for mycrotype
\SetExtraKerning[unit=space] %% add some space around en-dash
    {encoding={T1}, family={bch}, series={*}, size={normalsize}}
    {\textendash={300,300}}

\begin{document}

em-dash --- en-dash -- the end

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\SetExtraKerning` directive or change all `'---'` to `\textemdash{}` everything works, but shouldn't '---' be interpreted as `\textemdash` **before** microtype processing? What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't you directly type the emdash as `—`?

Comment: Or do search and replace once in a while `---` into `—` and `--` into `–`.

Comment: The source is produced by pandoc that changes the — (em-dash) to ---. So I already send its output to `sed` that changes every --- to `\textemdash{}` before ppassing to pdflatex. But my question was to know if it is a bug in microtype or I'm doing something wrong. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Good question, I'm sure someone will come along who knows the answer.

Comment: This seems to be a `pdftex` bug. The same happens with this plain example: `\pdfappendkern=1 \knaccode\font123=100 ---\bye` (`123` is the character code of the en-dash). I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix though (in fact, I don't even know where to report bugs nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

I’ve seen this problem described [at other places](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/microtype/) before and it seems that due to the order of things processed in the system, the kerning gets applied before TeX converts `---` or `--` into the appropriate dashes. I’m not an expert, but I could imagine that `microtype` hooks into the system at a certain place and only that place is possible at the moment or was simply chosen.

`\textemdash{}` or `\textendash{}` solve this. The curly parentheses are there to prevent a following space to be eaten by the command: `\textendash word` would produce “–word”.